# (flutter) FutureBuilder passing Map<> as property

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, dart-null-safety, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm trying to learn Flutter from a book that has been written before null safety, the code in it works perfectly if I add // @dart=2.9 at the beginning of the file, but gives some error without.

The error:

```
The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
```

Here is the code:

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: latestComic,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) => FutureBuilder(
          future: _fetchComic(i),
          builder: (context, comicResult) =>
          comicResult.hasData ?
          ComicTile(comic: comicResult.data) : // <- here gives the error when I remove 
                                               // @dart=2.9
              Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Divider(
                        height: 40,
                      ),
                      CircularProgressIndicator()
                    ],
                  )
              )
        ),
      ),

class ComicTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> comic;
  ComicTile({required this.comic});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Image.network(
        comic["img"],
        height:  50,
          width: 50,
      ),
      title: Text(comic["title"]),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => ComicPage(comic: comic)
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

So I tried to change

```
builder: (context, comicResult)
```

to

```
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Map>comicResult)
```

and now the error is:

```
The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
```

Then I tried

```
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>comicResult)
```

and now the error is:

```
The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
```

I tried to enter code here to solve passing parameters separately:

```
ComicTile(comicTitle: comicResult.data!["title"])
```

But I don't know how to pass images

How to pass `Map<String, dynamic>` to the `ComicTile` class?

Comment: how about passing like `comic: comicResult.data!`

Comment: can you add code for `_fetchComic` function

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Yeasin Sheikh this solves the issue:

```
comic: comicResult.data!
```